# Duplicates in Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar, synchronization

I had synched my Google Calendar to three separate Exchange accounts using Google Calendar Sync, and now I have three entries for each holiday (because they were added by default).

[image]

How do I merge these entries into one / remove the duplicates?

Comment: This question was bumped by a new answer. I’m voting to close this question because it's about Google Calendar Sync. It has been not supported for all users since a long time ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is go under the calendars synced list on the left of your calendar.
Expand to see all.
There will be each separate account listed. Under all but one acct. Unchecked the holidays box.
Problem solved.

Same for birthdays or any other entries you may have entered in multiple accts prior to syncing.

This way you are not deleting any Information from any one acct. As you may only access a single profile, say at work. Doing it this way you can easily toggle on and off what this accessed calendar displays without losing information or messing up the synced calendar view. You can do this for shared calendars, events from specific people and even target organizations.

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. Usually, each calendar has its own color. The screenshot shows all birthdays in the same color. On the other hand Google Calendar Sync is no longer supported for all users.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing built-in.

Your best bet is probably to export the data out, de-dupe it yourself, then import it back in.

Comment: If you do this you might find that they get re-created on next sync since the matching events are gone.